# How do I make the hidden notifications arrow point to the left in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, taskbar, notifications

In Windows Vista and earlier it use to point to the left to show hidden notifications extending the notifications area out. Since Windows 7 it's just an up arrow that shows a separate box instead. Is there anything I can do to make it function like Windows Vista and earlier even if it's installing some program or modifying something?

I am aware you can use "show hidden notifications" and make the arrow disappear altogether, but that's not what I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows feature you speak of (Up Arrow) in the System Tray came with Windows 7 (now gone), is there in the standard Desktop version of Windows 8, and is there in Windows 10 as well. The Up arrow is now the standard Windows behavior.

It is simple to manage the hidden icons to hide what you want and show what you want by dragging the icons to Hidden or to the Taskbar.

Note:  Looking at a Vista Machine here, the Properties of the Taskbar opens up a small dialogue box that deals with the Taskbar, Notification and Start Menu Properties.

This is a tiny fore-runner of what the Taskbar Properties and Up Arrow do in Windows 10.  There is no counterpart for Vista because the Vista dialogue is very limited.

Comment: What I am asking is if there's a way to change it back to the way it behaved before 7, whether that'd be some sort of registry editing, installing a program or coding.

Comment: I looked for something like that and found nothing. The Vista dialogue box that pops up is really old and in addition, Windows 10 keeps changing, so nothing like that on the horizon.

Comment: Hmm, well I'm using Windows 7 atm. I'm guessing there should be some utility out there similar to how Classic Shell works with replacing the Start Menu.

Comment: Classic Shell changes the start menu for sure and works in Seven, Eight and Ten if yo wish to use it. But it does not affect the Up Arrow (when I tried it on Windows 8)